# SerializeJSON Only Returning First Two Records

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have an issue where serializing an ORM relationship is only showing the first two records. The rest just show [] blank.

Here is an example relationship:

```
property name="endorsements" singularname="endorsement" fieldtype="one-to-many" lazy="false" fkcolumn="xxx" cfc="endorsements" remotingfetch="true";
```

Getting the JSON:

```
policy = entityLoad("policy",1018379202)[1];
serializeJSON( policy );
```

And a cut down part of the JSON:

```
{"id":12321,"endorsements":[{"effectiveDate":"July, 01 2009 00:00:00","active":true},
{"effectiveDate":"July, 01 2009 00:00:00","active":true},
"","","","","","","","",""]}
```

The empty strings should be other records in the relationship.

I've verified via debug files that the Hibernate query is bringing back all records and a cfdump shows this as well.

Thoughts?

Comment: Is there anything unusual about the content of the third record? Also, if you are dealing with a different "policy" record (which presumably will have different child "endorsement" records), do you still get exactly the same problem (only two records when there should be more)?

Comment: Are all the records there if you dump policy, or is it only losing them after you call serializeJSON()?

Comment: @JakeFeasel Nothing weird in the third record and I get this same problem with other entities.

Comment: @baynezy All the records are there if I dump policy and the SQL to retrieve them gets all records.

Comment: @SamFarmer I know this sounds a bit insane, but can you try serializing it as WDDX and see if you have the same issue?

Comment: I have this same issue, how strange. I can confirm it only happens on one-to-many relationships with remotingfetch="true". very strange bug. interested to see the outcome of this question.

Comment: Can you please enable SQL logging and post the SQL? Dumping an object is not quite the same.

Comment: What version of CF are you running (inc hotfixes)? Do you still get the same results when you run `serialiseJSON(policy[1])` instead of `entityLoad(...)[1]`?

Answer (score 4):

The bug occurs in coldfusion.runtime.JSONUtils.serializeJSON() at around line 409.

If you are serialising a persistent cfc, it adds the fully qualified name of the cfc to an ArrayList, which is passed around recursively.

Then there is an if() statement which tries to locate the cfc's fully qualified name and once it appears more than twice in the list, leaves the function early with "{}".

Not really sure what they were trying to accomplish with this if().
Possibly to handle circular references?

This bug was logged back in April: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3175667

Comment: While the code in JSONUtils is quite different in cf901 and cf10, both produce the same error - only the first 2 are serialised correctly - the rest are blank structs.